# Update cell value based on dates in other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I would like to:

1. Update a cell (A2) with a status. That could be a standardised list, for example: "Sent to Customer", "Customer Replied", "Task Closed".
2. There are three columns named - Sent to Customer (B1), Customer Replied (C1), Tasked Closed(D1). In those columns dates are entered once that stage is completed. For example: B2 = 01/01/2023, C2 = 02/01/2023, D2= 03/01/2023. In this example the cell in A2 should read "Task Closed".
3. The situation can arise where the most recent data could be in C3 - Customer Replied. In those instances A3 would need to read Customer Replied. The formula needs to find the earliest date in the columns B, C or D.

For Example
[image]

I've tried compiling the formula into a single cell for the data in rows 2 and 3. The compiled formula for row 2 is returning the wrong status? Why is that, what am I missing?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't want to redo work you have already done. I'm afraid without editing your question to address my ask will result in no answers or your question being marked for closure.

Comment: I have part of the solution. How long until the question will be marked for closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas don't match themselves.

```
ROW 2   
Offset      =OFFSET(B1,...   
Compiled    =OFFSET(A1,...

ROW 3   
Offset      =OFFSET(B1,...   
Compiled    =OFFSET(B1,...
```

Where you offset from has to line up with the range you search within the `MATCH()` function. I think you just have a typo. If the compiled formula for row 2 started with `=OFFSET(B1,` then I expect it would work fine.

---

Side note, you may want to throw at least one `$` in there to lock down the absolute referencesso you can copy / paste the formula down. I would use this as the compiled formula in row 2:

```
=OFFSET(B$1,,MATCH(MAX(C2:E2),C2:E2,0))
```

Alternatively:

```
=INDEX(C$1:E$1,MATCH(MAX(C2:E2),C2:E2,0))
```

Comment: Great spot, thank you!